# Was the Statue of Liberty's Captain America Shield a reference to any comic?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-no-way-home, hawkeye-2021

In both *Spider-Man: No Way Home* and *Hawkeye* (2021), we see the Statue of Liberty in New York City has a Captain America shield being affixed to it.

Was this in reference to a comic? Or a prior film? **Prior to 2021, did the Statue of Liberty ever have a Captain America shield in any Marvel property?**

Comment: https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Statue_of_Liberty#Redesigned FWIW

Comment: Also https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Statue_of_Liberty has no other shield references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know (through a few quick Google searches and [the Marvel wiki entry](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Statue_of_Liberty)), this is [unique to the MCU](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Statue_of_Liberty#Redesigned).

> On this Earth, the Statue of Liberty was at some point under construction to have a giant replica of Captain America's shield added to her torch-arm. Much of the scaffolding was destroyed and the shield fell off during the final confrontation between Spider-Man and a group of antagonistic visitors from other Earths.